# Netbeans Generate entity class from database failed

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans

I am trying to generate some entity classes from database in netbeans IDE 8.1, but I am facing an issue that tables and database are not displayed in the pop-up window

I have to mention that I created the connection properly and it is successfully connected to database I also have read the following question before:

[Generating entity class from database in netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991728/netbeans-generating-entity-class-from-database)

so I was thinking maybe the issue is due to wrong selection of schema,
  but when I go to the property window of my jdbc connection it doesn't display which schema is selected and nothing is displayed also when I needed to change it

[image: no schema is displayed to select]

I think it is possible to select a schema by editing the `glassfish-resources.xml` file manullay, but I have no idea what is the right tag to add to this file to get this done

any help is appreciated